# Binary Tree and LinkedList merge

Tags: c#, linked-list, binary-tree

I am trying to create a record system where the user enters a musical artists name into a textfield which then gets saved to a binary tree. It also gets added to a listbox where the user can then click on the specific artist name and then add albums to that artist which i want to save in a Linked List. If the user then wants to add another artist they just simply click in the artist textfield and add another one. The bit I am finding hard to understand is adding albums to an artist. I have developed several classes such as an Artist class with set and get methods of their names etc.

I want the user to save the albums and then they get saved to the artist name so that if they click the same artist again, the albums will be there with the choice of adding more. The albums are being saved in to a linked-list with the .addFirst method which appends them to the listbox where they can be seen.

I hope i have been clear of what I need help with. I have been trying for days now and dont seem to be getting no where.

```
      BINARY TREE CLASS WITH INSERT METHOD

    class BinarySrchTree<T> where T:IComparable
    {
      public Node<T> root;

      public BinarySrchTree()
      {
        root = null;
      }

      public BinarySrchTree(T item)
      {
        root = new Node<T>(item);
      }

      private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
       {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new Node<T>(item);
        }
        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
        }
        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
        }  
    }

    public void InsertItem(T item)
    {
        insertItem(item, ref root);
    }




    NODE CLASS FOR BINARY TREE

      namespace Assignment
      {
        class Node<T> where T:IComparable
        {
          private T data;
           public Node<T> Left, Right;

           public Node(T item)
           {
             data = item;
             Left = null;
             Right = null;
            }

           public T Data
           {
            set { data = value; }
            get { return data; }
           }

         }
        }

         ARTIST CLASS

    public class Artist : IComparable
    {
    public string name;
    public string members;
    public string albums;

    public Artist()
    {
    }

    public Artist(string name, string members, string album)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Members
    {
        get { return members; }
        set { members = value; }
    }

    public string Albums
    {
        get { return albums; }
        set { albums = value; }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Artist)
        {
            Artist other = (Artist)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
        if (obj is string)
        {
            string other = (string)obj;
            return members.CompareTo(other);
        }
        else
        {
            return -999;
        }
    }

     FORM CLASS (THE BIT I AM STRUGGLING WITH)

      public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    BinarySrchTree<string> bst = new BinarySrchTree<string>();
    LinkedList<string> albm = new LinkedList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string artist = textBox1.Text;
        string members = textBox3.Text;

        bst.InsertItem(artist);
        listBox1.Items.Add(artist + "\t" + members);

        Artist a = new Artist();
        a.Name = artist;
        a.Members = members;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string albums = textBox2.Text;
        albm.AddFirst(albums);
        listBox2.Items.Add(albums);

    }
  }
 }
```

I want to be able to add an artist by using the textbox and then add albums to that artist if thats possible. ANY HELP would be appreciated SOOO much!!

Answer (score 0):

I will modify the artist class to have a list of albums in there and a GUID field which will be unique per artist object.

```
public class Artist : IComparable
    {
    public string name;
    public string members;
    public string albums;
    public Guid artistID;
    public List<String> albums;

    public Artist()
    {
      artistID = new Guid();
    }

    public Artist(string name, string members, string album)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Members
    {
        get { return members; }
        set { members = value; }
    }

    public string Albums
    {
        get { return albums; }
        set { albums = value; }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Artist)
        {
            Artist other = (Artist)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
        if (obj is string)
        {
            string other = (string)obj;
            return members.CompareTo(other);
        }
        else
        {
            return -999;
        }
    }
```

Then add a search which function in the Binary Tree to get the node with the GUID. Retrieve the artist object for that node and add the album to the albums list for that node.

Search Tree

```
public Node<T> FindByValue(Guid value)
    {
        // search the list for the value
        foreach (Node<T> node in Items)
            if (node.artistID.Equals(value))
                return node;

        // if we reached here, we didn't find a matching node
        return null;
    }
```

Add album

```
node.albums.add(album);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still struggling to understand how to implement it. I would like it so that the artist gets added to a listbox and then the user clicks the listbox entry and then adds an album to that artist through the GUI

Comment: This should still work. You are just keeping one model object and can manage everything using it. So when you add an artidt you create a new object and on adding a new album add it to the list of albums for the selected artist object. Also why are you using a tree structure for artist objects.